# Как сделать игровое управление с помощью клавиш W,S,A,D?

Tags: javascript, html, keydown

У меня есть 4 кнопки : Up, Down,Left,Right.Которые отвечают за управление в canvas с помощью события click. Как реализовать управление с помощью кнопок W,S,A,D как в играх? Буду благодарен , если поможете.

```js
let myGamePiece;
function startGame() {
    myGameArea.start();
    myGamePiece = new Component(30, 30, 20, 0, 2 * Math.PI, 'red')
}
let myGameArea = {
    canvas: document.createElement('canvas'),
    start: function () {
        this.canvas.width = 480;
        this.canvas.height = 270;
        this.context = this.canvas.getContext('2d');
        document.body.insertBefore(this.canvas, document.body.childNodes[0]);
        this.interval = setInterval(updateGameArea, 20);
    },
    clear: function () {
        this.context.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
    }
};

//Круг
function Component(x, y, radius, startAng, endAng, color) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.radius = radius;
    this.startAng = startAng;
    this.endAng = endAng;
    this.speedX = 0;
    this.speedY = 0;
    this.update = function () {
        ctx = myGameArea.context;
        ctx.fillStyle = color;
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.radius, this.startAng, this.endAng);
        ctx.fill();
    };
    this.newPos = function () {
        this.x += this.speedX;
        this.y += this.speedY;
    }

};
function updateGameArea() {
    myGameArea.clear();
    myGamePiece.newPos();
    myGamePiece.update()
};

function moveUp() {
    myGamePiece.speedY -= 1;
};

function moveDown() {
    myGamePiece.speedY += 1;
};

function moveLeft() {
    myGamePiece.speedX -= 1;
};


function moveRight() {
    myGamePiece.speedX += 1;
};
let up = document.getElementById('up');
let down = document.getElementById('down');
let left = document.getElementById('left');
let right = document.getElementById('right');
up.addEventListener('click' ,(ev) => {
    moveUp();
});
down.addEventListener('click', (ev) => {
    moveDown();
});
left.addEventListener('click', (ev) => {
    moveLeft();
});
right.addEventListener('click' ,(ev) => {
    moveRight()
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте `keyup`, `keydown` или `keypress`

Как работает:

```js
    document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
        if (event.code == 'KeyW') {
            alert('Вверх')
        }
        if (event.code == 'KeyA') {
            alert('Влево')
        }
        if (event.code == 'KeyS') {
            alert('Вниз')
        }
        if (event.code == 'KeyD') {
            alert('Вправо')
        }
    });
```

Пример с `keypress` (Добавил в пример обработку как русских, так и латинских):

```js
    document.addEventListener('keypress', (event) => {
        const keyName = event.key;
        if (keyName == "w" || keyName == "W" || keyName == 'ц' || keyName == 'Ц'){
            alert('вверх');
        }
        if (keyName == "s" || keyName == "S" || keyName == 'ы' || keyName == 'Ы'){
            alert('вниз');
        }
        if (keyName == "a" || keyName == "A" || keyName == 'ф' || keyName == 'Ф'){
            alert('влево');
        }
        if (keyName == "d" || keyName == "D" || keyName == 'в' || keyName == 'В'){
            alert('вправо');
        }
    });
```

В Вашем примере:

```js
let myGamePiece;
function startGame() {
    myGameArea.start();
    myGamePiece = new Component(30, 30, 20, 0, 2 * Math.PI, 'red')
}
let myGameArea = {
    canvas: document.createElement('canvas'),
    start: function () {
        this.canvas.width = 480;
        this.canvas.height = 270;
        this.context = this.canvas.getContext('2d');
        document.body.insertBefore(this.canvas, document.body.childNodes[0]);
        this.interval = setInterval(updateGameArea, 20);
    },
    clear: function () {
        this.context.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
    }
};

//Круг
function Component(x, y, radius, startAng, endAng, color) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.radius = radius;
    this.startAng = startAng;
    this.endAng = endAng;
    this.speedX = 0;
    this.speedY = 0;
    this.update = function () {
        ctx = myGameArea.context;
        ctx.fillStyle = color;
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.radius, this.startAng, this.endAng);
        ctx.fill();
    };
    this.newPos = function () {
        this.x += this.speedX;
        this.y += this.speedY;
    }

};
function updateGameArea() {
    myGameArea.clear();
    myGamePiece.newPos();
    myGamePiece.update()
};

function moveUp() {
    myGamePiece.speedY -= 1;
};

function moveDown() {
    myGamePiece.speedY += 1;
};

function moveLeft() {
    myGamePiece.speedX -= 1;
};


function moveRight() {
    myGamePiece.speedX += 1;
};
let up = document.getElementById('up');
let down = document.getElementById('down');
let left = document.getElementById('left');
let right = document.getElementById('right');
up.addEventListener('click' ,(ev) => {
    moveUp();
});
down.addEventListener('click', (ev) => {
    moveDown();
});
left.addEventListener('click', (ev) => {
    moveLeft();
});
right.addEventListener('click' ,(ev) => {
    moveRight()
})

document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) { // Добавляем нажатие кнопок
    if (event.code == 'KeyW') {
    moveUp();
    }
    if (event.code == 'KeyA') {
    moveLeft();
    }
    if (event.code == 'KeyS') {
    moveDown();
    }
    if (event.code == 'KeyD') {
    moveRight()
    }
});
```